# Remove extra line in output in Python

Tags: python, string, loops

This is a code to print a right faced arrow in Python3. Even though I am getting the output, I am getting some extra lines between the 2 loops. How can I remove the extra lines?

Code:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n+1):
    print(" "*(i*2) + "*"*(n-i))
for j in range(n,-1,-1):
    print(" "*(j*2) + "*"*(n-j))
```

My Output:
n = 5

```
*****
  ****
    ***
      **
        *


        *
      **
    ***
  ****
*****
```

Expected Output:

```
*****    
  ****   
    ***  
      ** 
        *
      ** 
    ***  
  ****   
*****
```

Answer (score 2):

just test it:

```py
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n-1):
    print(" "*(i*2) + "*"*(n-i))
for j in range(n-1,-1,-1):
    print(" "*(j*2) + "*"*(n-j))
```

input

```
6
```

output

```
******
  *****
    ****
      ***
        **
          *
        **
      ***
    ****
  *****
******
```

Comment: Yes it worked. I forgot about the middle *. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, just needs some changes at start-end of the loops. Try this:

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    print(" "*(i*2) + "*"*(n-i))
for j in range(n-2,-1,-1):
    print(" "*(j*2) + "*"*(n-j))
```

Output for n=5:

```
*****
  ****
    ***
      **
        *
      **
    ***
  ****
*****
```